# Ubuntu 14.10: Extremely bad CPU Performance and heat

Tags: performance, 14.10, sandy-bridge

Ubuntu is running extremely slow due poor CPU performance, I have fairly good notebook (4GB ram 2.4Ghz Sandy Bridge CPU) and I know thats the cause is the p_state driver from Intel (the substitue of ACPI mode).

The only way to get a good performance is instaling cpufrequtils and using "sudo cpufreq-set -g performance", but the powersave option should be the new "ondemand" mode as far that I know. Besides that any configuration still makes my notebook a little hot.

Is there any bug or configuration that I need to do?

Comment: Just to exemplify, acessing the dash is very slow with powersave setting, after changing manually to performance everthing is smooth again.